nand2tetris ALU Question
So im working on the ALU for the nand2tetris course online (for fun) and it's "design" is supposed to be as such:
// Implementation: Manipulates the x and y inputs
// and operates on the resulting values, as follows:
// if (zx == 1) sets x = 0        // 16-bit constant
// if (nx == 1) sets x = !x       // bitwise not
// if (zy == 1) sets y = 0        // 16-bit constant
// if (ny == 1) sets y = !y       // bitwise not
// if (f == 1)  sets out = x + y  // integer 2's complement addition
// if (f == 0)  sets out = x & y  // bitwise and
// if (no == 1) sets out = !out   // bitwise not

CHIP ALU {
    IN  
        x[16], y[16],  // 16-bit inputs        
        zx, // zero the x input?
        nx, // negate the x input?
        zy, // zero the y input?
        ny, // negate the y input?
        f,  // compute (out = x + y) or (out = x & y)?
        no; // negate the out output?
    OUT 
        out[16], // 16-bit output
        zr,      // if (out == 0) equals 1, else 0
        ng;      // if (out < 0)  equals 1, else 0

    PARTS:
    BUILTIN ALU;
}

https://imgur.com/a/BagdG2T
Above is what I have so far:
For those that have difficulty reading it says 0/false on the zx/zy 2-1 mux's. and the add16 is a chip we've already implemented (just a 16 bit adder).
I initially struggled and was like "how do I do this" then I watched like a single part of someone describing designing the zx part and realized Duh I should be used muxes. But I don't know if using a bunch of 2-1 muxes makes sense? Also Im not sure if chaining them is the right thing either? (Or if order matters) I just went by how they showed in the course (Which they checked zx then nx etc...)
Am I on the right track at all?
Also for the status bits im thinking zr I nand16 the out with 0 (Since NAND 0 and 0 makes 1 and otherwise 0) and for ng Im a little unsure, but I guess I could check the MSB to see if it's a 1 which would make it a negative? Im unsure there.
